# webpack 404s will fallback to //index.html

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack

I'm trying to run an empty angular template to start working on a new project.

I'm confused because when I'm starting basic angular template I'm getting a blank page with HTTP 400 error.
Here are my very simple commands:
[image]

Does anyone have an idea of what's going?

My node & npm versions

> node -v v10.16.3
>
> npm -v 6.9.0

Comment: what's the error in console? Did you modified any code in it?

Comment: There is no error in console, just HTTP 400 from http://localhost:4200/
I've just run ng serve -o without any modifications